# AngularJS simple addition not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a simple addition using the following code but for some reason the result is a simple string concatenation instead of arithmetic addition. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here and how to fix this problem? Thanks

```
$scope.budget = localStorageService.get('budget'); //this returns 5000
$scope.toBeAdded = localStorageService.get('newAddition'); //this return 500

$scope.NewBudget = $scope.budget + $scope.toBeAdded; //return 5000500 instead of 5500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage is stored as a string. If you need an integer, you need to parseInt with the returned value. For example:

```
$scope.budget = parseInt(localStorageService.get('budget'), 10); //this returns 5000
$scope.toBeAdded = parseInt(localStorageService.get('newAddition'), 10); //this return 500

$scope.NewBudget = $scope.budget + $scope.toBeAdded;
```

If you are expecting decimal numbers, of course you need to use parseFloat instead of parseInt.

Comment: Don't forget to add the radix when you use parseInt.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $scope.budget and $scope.toBeAdded are being returned as strings instead of integers; however I don't think you have shared enough code for us to diagnose why.  Try converting:

```
$scope.NewBudget = Number($scope.budget) + Number($scope.toBeAdded)
```

It uses the [Number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) function to convert the strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$scope.budget = parseInt(localStorageService.get('budget'), 10);
$scope.toBeAdded = parseInt(localStorageService.get('newAddition'), 10);
```

It will make sure those value are passed as integers. Don't forget the radix at the end of parseInt().

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are probably strings. You can turn them into numbers using `Number(x)`